# Would nginx allow me to access internal websites from the internet via subdomains without specifying the internal port?

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

For years I’ve just been forwarding ports from my router to the respective machine’s IP address and using something like http://example.com:9999.  But since I’ve been using lots of IoT devices, I’m becoming more concerned about not using SSL.  I also don’t like exposing the port number, lest some hacker guesses about some of my services.  Yes, I could change the external port, but i would prefer to use a subdomain as that name instantly tells me what the service is being used for without requiring me to look up the service’s port elsewhere.

Let’s say I have two websites on two Ubuntu machines that I can access internally as follows:

1. https://192.168.1.20:6668
2. https://192.168.1.30:6669

And I have a machine running Windows IIS (192.168.1.40) that I can access with https (I use IIS to force a redirect to https)

3. https://site3.example.com
4. https://site4.example.com

I want to be able to access them from the internet using: (and have all of them redirect to https)

```
https://site1.example.com
https://site2.example.com
https://site3.example.com
https://site4.example.com
```

Prior to using Ubuntu and with a single Windows machine I could have just used host headers in IIS to accomplish this.  But since you can only forward an external port to one internal machine, I would need some sort of service like nginx and have that be responsible for marshalling the requests to the correct machine.  Since it appears I’m going this route, I might as well get rid of the IIS http redirect (and possibly host headers) and have everything handled by nginx. This would require me use different ports for SSL on IIS per site, but that’s not a big deal.

If I were to have my router to forward TCP ports 80,443 to 192.168.1.10 (running nginx)  I know I could create redirects to ensure that all http requests get forced over to https, as well as use the subdomain to determine which machine and port to forward the request. But will nginx be able to hide the internal port from the internet client?  Is this part of what is meant by nginx being a reverse proxy?

ETA: How do SSL certificates come into play?  I plan on using Let’s Encrypt to get SSL certs.  As my in my example above, https://site1.example.com will route to http://192.168.1.20:6668. Where should I be using Let’s Encrypt to generate these certificates?  It makes sense I should have to do this on the 192.168.1.20 website, but do I also need to do this on nginx since that is where the redirect is taking place?

Comment: 192.168.1.20 needn't know anything about SSL. It would be better for this to be regular HTTP.

Comment: But if someone comes in with https, then how will nginx be able to redirect to the internal service?

Comment: It doesn't redirect. It forwards the request directly. nginx is working as a proxy service.

Comment: What proxy_pass does is takes the original request and sends it to the backend service, and then returns the response. The backend service is completely hidden from the end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this should be fairly straightforward to do with nginx.

Firstly you'll want a default server rule to redirect all http requests to https. Something like this...

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Then you would add the configurations for each of your virtual servers. Something like ...

```
    server {
            listen 443;

            server_name site1.example.com;

            ssl_certificate     site1.example.com.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key site1.example.com.key;
            ...

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.20:6668;
                    proxy_set_header Host            $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            }
    }
```

You'll need to add whatever extra bits you need to correctly terminate the SSL request in nginx.

In your router you would then only allow incoming requests on port 80 and 443, so the internal ports cannot be accessed directly.

Note, those proxy_set_header statements may not be required. This is just so the backend servers receive the correct host header and remote IP address, in case they need this.

### update

You wouldn't install the SSL certificates on your back-end servers. Only on the public facing nginx server. There is no need to secure the connection from nginx to your private servers, as this happens within your private network.

Just to re-iterate, the only server which is actually exposed directly to the internet will be your nginx server. The private back-end servers won't be accessible outside your network, so won't need SSL's installed.

It's a common use-case to have a public facing SSL-enabled nginx instance forwarding requests to private servers via HTTP.

Comment: I updated my question to address to ask about using Let’s Encrypt.  From your example, since it looks like it is just doing a redirect, does this mean I don’t need an SSL certificate for site1.example.com on the nginx instance?

Comment: Yes, you'll need an ssl cert installed for each domain. Instructions can be found here ... http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: I've updated my answer to show where you'd put your SSL options,